# react not using supplied key prop

Tags: reactjs

I have a fuzzy search test running at https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-faraday-ucilw?file=/src/App.js

However, it is not accepting the unique key prop even though I am passing in a unique ID.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the error:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `MyComponent`. 
    in ul (at search.jsx:25)
    in MyComponent (at App.js:13)
    in div (at App.js:12)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)
```

App.js Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MyComponent from "./search";

const customers = [
  { id: "1", name: "Bob", email: "aa@aa.com" },
  { id: "2", name: "Foo", email: "mm@mm.com" }
];

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyComponent customers={customers} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Search.js Code:

```
import React from "react";
import useFuse from "react-use-fuse";

function MyComponent({ customers }) {
  const options = {
    keys: ["name", "email"]
  };

  const { result, search, term } = useFuse({
    data: customers,
    options
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={e => search(e.target.value)}
        value={term}
        placeholder="Search for a customer..."
      />

      {console.log(term)}
      {result &&
        result.map(customers => (
          <ul key={customers.id}>
            <li>{customers.name}</li>
            <li>{customers.email}</li>
          </ul>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: What evidence do you have that proves "it is not accepting the unique key prop"?

Comment: There is a console error in the code sandbox

Comment: Can you post the error here?  It is best to provide as much context as possible without making people run your application.  As each hurdle people have to overcome may sway them to leave before answering your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `result` array which structure changes when you filter it.

**Unfiltered:**

```
[{id, name, email}, ...]
```

**Filtered:**

```
[{ item: {id, name, email } }, ...]
```

So when you map `result`, there are no `id` hence the error message.

One way to fix this is to check if the objects returned by map have a property called `item`:

```
  {result &&
    result.map(customer => {
      if (customer.item) customer = customer.item;
      return (
        <div key={customer.id}>
          <p>{customer.name}</p>
          <p>{customer.email}</p>
        </div>
      );
    })}
```

By the way, I renamed `customers` in map to `customer`, because `customers` is already declared as `props`

Comment: I suppose you have no control on how useFuse works, right?

Comment: That's right, an external library for fuzzy searching within react.

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique 'key' prop." means that each 'li' in your code should have a key.  In this case you can fix this by making a composite key combining the id with the field names

example:

```
<ul key={customers.id}>
  <li key={`${customers.id}-name`}>{customers.name}</li>
  <li key={`${customers.id}-email`}>{customers.email}</li>
</ul>
```